# Invoking Actions from Moq

Tags: callback, action, moq, anonymous, func

I've got a service with a method that takes two `Action`s, one for success and one for failure. Each `Action` takes a Result parameter that contains additional information...

```
void AuthoriseUser(AuthDetails loginDetails, 
  Action<AuthResult> onSuccess, 
  Action<AuthResult> onFailure);
```

I'm writing a unit test for a class that is dependant on that service, and I want to test that this class does the correct things in the `onSuccess(...)` and `onFailure(...)` callbacks. These are either private or anonymous methods, so how do I setup the mocked service to call either Action?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `Callback` method (see also in the [Moq quickstart](https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) Callbacks section) to configure a callback which gets called with the original arguments of the mocked method call (`AuthoriseUser`) so you can call your `onSuccess` and `onFailure` callbacks there:

```cs
var moq = new Mock<IMyService>();
moq.Setup(m => m.AuthoriseUser(It.IsAny<AuthDetails>(),
                                It.IsAny<Action<AuthResult>>(),
                                It.IsAny<Action<AuthResult>>()))
    .Callback<AuthDetails, Action<AuthResult>, Action<AuthResult>>(
    (loginDetails, onSuccess, onFailure) =>
        {
            onSuccess(new AuthResult()); // fire onSuccess
            onFailure(new AuthResult()); // fire onFailure
        });
```

Comment: How can i do this if instead of passing the action in method, i am having it as a public property and call Action?.Invoke in my class!