# C# Moq. testing for function having multiple action parameters

Tags: c#, moq, unit-testing

I have following code, and willing to do Moq testing for DoDivision method of DoMath class, I need to test successful and unsuccessful case(i.e. divide by zero). So, how I should create Moq object of Math class and pass it to DoDivision and make assert on output?

```
public interface IMath
{
    void Divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, Action<double> callback, Action<string> errorCallback);
}

public class Math : IMath
{
    public void Divide(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, Action<double> callback, Action<string> errorCallback)
    {
        if (secondNumber == 0)
        {
            errorCallback("Arithmetic exception: Division by zero is not allowed.");
        }
        else
        {
            callback(firstNumber / secondNumber);
        }
    }
}

public class DoMaths
{
    public IMath math;

    public void DoDivision(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, Action<string> callback, Action<string> errorCallback)
    {
        math.Divide(firstNumber, secondNumber, ans =>
        {
            callback(String.Format("{0} / {1} = {2}", firstNumber, secondNumber, ans.ToString()));
        }, error =>
        {
            errorCallback(error);
        });
    }
}

DoMaths doMaths = new DoMaths();
doMaths.math = new Math.Math();
doMaths.DoDivision(2, 0, ans =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(ans);
}, error => {
    Console.WriteLine(error);
});
```

Comment: I assume this is a theoretical sample. Normally you would not mock any class that you have control over, obviously. 
Maybe this helps in regards to mocking multiple callbacks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167081/invoking-actions-from-moq

Comment: Thanks hSchroedl, it did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this case, got help from "hSchroedl" comment. I am publishing mine solution code, so some one can have help in such case.

```
const int firstNumberParam = 2;
const int secondNumberParam = 1;

var mathMoq = new Moq.Mock<Math.IMath>();
mathMoq.Setup(m => m.Divide(
    It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), //secondNumberParam,
    It.IsAny<Action<double>>(), It.IsAny<Action<string>>()
)).Callback<Int32, Int32, Action<double>, Action<string>>((firstNumber, secondNumber, successCallback, errorCallback) =>
{
    successCallback(firstNumberParam);
    errorCallback("Arithmetic exception: Division by zero is not allowed.");
});

DoMaths doMaths = new DoMaths();
doMaths.math = mathMoq.Object;

doMaths.DoDivision(firstNumberParam, secondNumberParam, success =>
{
    Assert.AreEqual("2 / 1 = 2", success);
}, error =>
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Arithmetic exception: Division by zero is not allowed.", error);
});
```